# How to cache images on the client that are served from a controller action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image, caching

### Setup

---

I have a website written in ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 that displays a number of images. Some of these images are static and are served up from the file system directly in the view:

```
<img src="~/Content/images/StaticImage.jpg?1" />
```

The rest of the images come from a database and are served up using a controller action:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetDatabaseImage(long rowId, long rowTimestamp)
{
    return this.File(GetDatabaseImage(rowId, rowTimestamp), "image/jpeg");
}
```

**View**

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetDatabaseImage", "Image", new { rowId = Model.RowId, rowTimestamp = Model.RowTimestamp })" />
```

I want all of these images to be cached on the client and in the case of the database images, on the server as well and hence I have added an OutputCache attribute to the GetDatabaseImage action:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

and also used the following configuration in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
```

### Problem

---

The caching works perfectly for the static images, the same can't be said for the database images. Here is what Chrome Dev tools is showing me when I access the page (after it's already been loaded once).

[image]

As you can see, the static image is cached correctly on the client and no server connection is made but for the database image it is still checking the server to see if the image has been modified. I do not want it to do this as I've specified a cachebuster parameter (rowTimestamp).

### Question

---

How can I get the database images to behave in the same way as the static images?

Comment: Have you tried with `Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client`?

Comment: No I haven't, my understanding was the default Location of "Any" meant it would cache everywhere it could.

Comment: Setting the location to Client does indeed solve the problem. I am still unclear as to why setting the location to Any doesn't behave in the same way though

Comment: As far as I can remember, `Any` means **can** be cached on Server, Client etc, but `Client` means **is** cached on Client (have previously read a good article about this but cant find it - will let you know when I do)